# Objective C: Image not displayed correctly in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I have created a new image to be included in a barbutton item as seen below

[image]

However, when I try to add the image to the UIBarButtonItem (as seen in code below)

```
UIBarButtonItem *newQuestionButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneButton_text"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(displayNewQuestion)];
```

I get the following result

[image]

What can I do to display the actual color of the text in the original image in the barbutton?

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it shows as `white` is because only `alpha values` in the image are used to create the bar button image. Whatever image you provide is converted into a image with `shades of white`, based on the `alpha values`. The image must be modified to conform to the `iOS Human Interface Guidelines`:

1. Use the PNG format.
2. Use pure white with appropriate alpha.
3. Do not include a drop shadow.
4. Use anti-aliasing.
5. If you decide to add a bevel, be sure that it is 90° (to help you do this, imagine a light source positioned at the top of the icon).
6. For toolbar and navigation bar icons, create an icon that measures about 20 x 20 pixels.
7. For tab bar icons, create an icon that measures about 30 x 30 pixels.

You can find the docs here:

[Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

Comment: thanks for your response. So does that mean that I cannot change the text color from white to grey in a uibutton?

Comment: @Zhen Yes you can, grey is a shade of white.